# Why is the Timestamp constructor the fastest way to parse a date string?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm working on speeding up conversions of strings to Timestamps, and I noticed that using the Timestamp constructor appeared to be the fasted way to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
from time import perf_counter as pc

test_time = '2016-12-01 19:44:47.891124'

t0 = pc()
for _ in range(100000):
    pd.Timestamp.strptime(test_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
pc() - t0
# 1.6517095469753258

t0 = pc()
for _ in range(100000):
    pd.to_datetime(test_time)
pc() - t0
# 5.428138378018048

t0 = pc()
for _ in range(100000):
    pd.Timestamp(test_time)
pc() - t0
# 0.20555895700817928
```

I'm surprised that the constructor is actually more performant than the `strptime` method, since in the latter we're explicitly stating how to parse the string. What is the Timestamp constructor doing that is so much better than these other approaches?

Comment: This code is pretty confusing to read. You probably shouldn't format things like this in python.

Comment: Did you [look at it](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tslib.pyx#L249) to find out? Pandas is open source.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson the code was sufficient for time testing, but i've updated it to make it more readable

Comment: @jonrsharpe I took a look at the source, but I'm having trouble finding my way around it. Where is Timestamp's or _Timestamp's \_\_init\_\_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process you're using is inefficient.  You should be batch converting your dates all at once with `pd.to_datetime` instead of doing each one individually.

Consider the following setup:

```
test_dts = ['2016-12-01 19:44:47.891124']*10**5
```

What you're timing is essentially parsing each date one at a time:

```
%timeit [pd.to_datetime(dt) for dt in test_dts]
1 loop, best of 3: 5.33 s per loop
```

You should just batch convert them in one step:

```
%timeit pd.to_datetime(test_dts)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.6 ms per loop
```

Doing each one individually with `pd.Timestamp` is slower:

```
%timeit [pd.Timestamp(dt) for dt in test_dts]
10 loops, best of 3: 166 ms per loop
```